# FIX protocol in Python - implement login and request for streaming quote

Tags: python, quickfix, fix-protocol

I am trying to implement basic FIX requests with python quickfix (FIX 4.2), however the documentation is sparse for me to understand it fully (and i have done quite a bit of research ,links at the end of the question - so please be assured that its not a question without doing any digging up)

### Login request --- A

```
8=FIX.4.2 | 9=108 | 35=A | 34=1 | 49=ACCOUNTXXX | 52=20161116-00:00:15.281 | 56=CNX | 553=ACCOUNTXXXSTR1 | 554=Stater123 | 98=0 | 108=60 | 141=Y | 10=133 |
```

#### this will be the expected  Login response

```
8=FIX.4.2 | 9=77 | 35=A | 49=CNX | 34=1 | 52=20161116-00:00:17.928 | 56= ACCOUNTXXXSTR1 | 98=0 | 108=60 | 141=Y | 10=140 |
```

#### Request for live/streaming quote in EUR/USD    --- B

```
8=FIX.4.2 | 9=142 | 35=V | 34=8 | 49=ACCOUNTXXX | 52=20161116-12:19:48.269 | 56=CNX | 146=1 | 55=EUR/USD | 262=2016110213351833862 | 263=2 | 264=1 | 265=1 | 266=Y | 267=2 | 269=0 | 269=1 | 10=110 |
```

#### Response will come like this and I need to handle it by keeping a socket/stream open --- STREAM

```
8=FIX.4.2 | 9=227 | 35=X | 49=CNX | 34=241 | 52=20161116-12:20:03.651 | 56=ACCOUNTXXX | 262=2016110213351834170 | 268=2 | 279=0 | 269=0 | 278=141 | 55=EUR/USD | 270=1.76371 | 15=GBP | 271=1000000 | 346=1 | 279=0 | 269=1 | 278=142 | 55=EUR/USD | 270=1.76406 | 15=GBP | 271=1000000 | 346=1 | 10=223 |
```

#### send heartbeat after every 60 seconds   - C

```
8=FIX.4.2 | 9=59 | 35=0 | 34=3 | 49=ACCOUNTXXX | 52=20161116-00:01:15.868 | 56=CNX | 10=054 |
```

I wanted a bit of advice and some basic code structure on how to set up the Python code to send A, B, C and open a socket/stream to keep reading the data in STREAM and logging it to console

Where have I looked already?

https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix/blob/master/examples/executor/python/executor.py

https://futures.io/matlab-r-project-python/35213-python-quickfix.html

https://github.com/tianyilai/QuickFix-python-client/tree/master/spec

however, the documentation and the examples are sparse and I am struggling to find my way through
Thanks

Comment: Did you read the actual docs on the QF homepage? They contain Python examples.  http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/

Answer (score 10):

**A --** a login request is sent automatically by QuickFix when you call `initiator.start()`. The key bit of documentation you need for this is [here](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/python/application_2.html), with PYTHON example translation:

```
import quickfix

if len(sys.argv) <  2: return          # FAIL to have a mandatory number of args
fileName = sys.argv[1]                 # .SET fileName ( a configuration file )

try:
        settings     = quickfix.SessionSettings( fileName )
        application  = quickfix.MyApplication()
        storeFactory = quickfix.FileStoreFactory( settings )
        logFactory   = quickfix.FileLogFactory(   settings )
        acceptor     = quickfix.SocketAcceptor(   application, storeFactory, settings, logFactory )
        #                      .SocketInitiator( ... )  # Ref. below
        acceptor.start() #-------------------------------

        # while condition == true: do something
        #
        # pass; # onEoLife:

        acceptor.stop() #--------------------------------

except quickfix.ConfigError, e:
        print e
```

> [<sub>( ***Cit.:*** )</sub> ... sample code above shows how you might start up a FIX-protocol  **`acceptor`** which listens on a socket.](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/application.html)  <sub>...</sub> 
>  If you rather wanted an initiator ( to setup a session from your side ) you would replace the `acceptor` in this code fragment with a **`SocketInitiator`**.

The line `settings = quickfix.SessionSettings(fileName)` loads the configuration file, and many of the key fields are taken from there. [**See** config file docs.](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/configuration.html)

**B --** In order to request live data you need to send a 35=V message to your counterparty. In order to do this, you define a `MarketDataRequest` message, which has some variables, and you send that message to your counterparty. [**See** here](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/python/sending_messages_3.html). Pay attention though, I think that the documentation is wrong here and to send the mssage you need to call `fix.Session_sendToTarget(message)`.

**C --** You don't need to worry about this, QuickFix handles heartbeats and logging back on after disconnects etc. automatically. You set the heartbeat interval (e.g. 60 seconds) in the config file **`fileName`**. [**See** config file docs.](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/configuration.html)

Comment: Can you also explain after Step-B once the valid message is sent, where to capture the stream? I send the message successfully but get nothing in return in the log file.

Comment: Hello @wapiti I followed your mentioned steps and get this error:
"fix.Session_sendToTarget(mdr)
quickfix.SessionNotFound: Session Not Found".

 Will you please help me out what is the reason behind it. I am implementing quickfix python in my application get market data.